# create database if not exists php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a database if it does not exist. Code is here:

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pw');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Make studentdb the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('StudentDB', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
  $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE StudentDB';

  if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
      echo "Database StudentDB created successfully\n";
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

Error creating database: Access denied for user 'myusernamehere' to database 'StudentDB'

the user has dba permissions...I'm guessing this is a permission error for my user....how can I give the user permission through the script and make this script work?

Comment: You can't through this code, you'd need to `grant` your user permissions to create databases with your root user (or another user that has grant access.)

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the users you are trying to use have no priviledges to use `CREATE`

try to switch to another user that have all the priviledges needed on manipulting the database or
add the needed priviledges to the user you are using

Comment: I've created a user with dba....inside of phpmyadmin I'm simply trying CREATE DATABASE test; and I'm still getting the error permission denied for user

Answer (score 0):

it happend to me and the following solved the problem:

1. first before using code to editing the database go to the main
   **localhost/index.php** page  then choose *phpMyAdmin database manager*
2. after than make sure that you are loged in as admin